# Can I use my developer Org for integration with Trello or slack?

Tags: developer-org

Can i integrate Slack and/or Trello to my Salesforce Deveoper Org?

I realise I can do this in a purchased org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes, you can do this. Thats why Salesforce provided them so that we can complete our POC in them without affecting live code. Or if you want to do self-learning then we can use them.

As developer org support most of the feature except some paid apps/paid feature.